# Replace only raw text in HTML string

Tags: html, ruby

I have a string:

```
html_string =
'<span><span class=\"ip\"></span> Do not stare <span class=\"img\"></span>  at the monitor continuously </span>\r\n'
```

I want to replace the character `s` in the raw text (not in the html tags) of `html_string` with `<span class="highlighted">s</span>`.

The result should be:

```
'<span><span class=\"ip\"></span> Do not <span class="highlighted">s</span>tare <span class=\"img\"></span>  at the monitor continuou<span class="highlighted">s</span>ly </span>\r\n'
```

What I did is:

```
html_string.gsub(/s/, '<span class="highlighted">s</span>')
```

but this replaces all occurrences of the `s` character regardless of raw text or a tag. I want to replace it skipping html tags and its attributes. How it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Do not pretend to be ideal answer, just to give you a way where to go:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_string = '<span><span class="ip"></span> Do not stare <span class="img"></span>  at the monitor continuously </span>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html_string)
spans = doc.css('span')
spans.each do |span|
  span.xpath('text()').each do |text|
    if text.content =~ /stare/
      text.content = text.content.sub(/stare/, '<span class="highlighted">s</span>tare')
    end
  end
end
p doc.to_html.gsub(/\&lt;/, '<').gsub(/\&gt;/, '>')
```

Which output is:

```
#=> "<span><span class=\"ip\"></span> Do not <span class=\"highlighted\">s</span>tare <span class=\"img\"></span>  at the monitor continuously </span>"
```

So, here we are looking for all `span`s and checking them for content that has `stare` word. Then we change content. That's all, and learn nokogiri.

Answer (score 1):

That's really simple: parse the html, replace in the text nodes, print to html.

[Nokogiri](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/) seems to be popular for that in Ruby.